# Vega lite plot state transition in a day

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I need to plot the state transition of different agents in a 24h span. I can visualize the transitions:

[image]

But I need this to be a 24h span (from 00:00 to 00:00 of the next day)

I tried adding [scaling](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#example-customizing-domain-for-a-time-scale):

```
"timeUnit": "hours",
"scale": {"domain": [{"hours": 0}, {"hours": 24}]}
```

And now I see the time span in my X axis, but the visualization is broken:

[image]

[This is my code in Vega Lite Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBExJMDCIZ0I4w2XEUqzKVKGJJBDNWgDaoJGRwsphoIBBI6kgwjiYRIegATAAMCQDM-EkAjPyZqQAqCZmoqQBsqGKplACcqQDsAFoxpuYQoXmRshB0uo5ByqHJaRnZuQVFqQAc5ZU1DSAAvgr+gcGh4ZHRSrHq8SCD6Vk5+YXFUxXVdY1bzRahAPIAZg92Dkp9AykHI8fjVdMXc0WyyCu3WUSacQ+Q0OoxOqT+51mVzCN1a6DushevVk-USn2GRzGqAALElUAkSpQSpcFksQAEQWsIuDrpC8dDvkTSeTKdS5qyWm1IjRZCKyNjcXt8TCfiSxDyqTSgfSVrscHBMHB1BCdlCvoTMrVimVETSBbd0O0kJ1unIJXqCaNDad-kjacDVuh1Zrtazdez9U6jZNXWaUWYLSBHs8Ra8QO8A478s74aHAXSGZ6QN6tTrdvsk3kUwiZmHYoL0ZjY-bEzKi0buRTFemPWqNbm-fnpZznY3eWXUUKkCKxTWpRyDQ35U2+Y15gBdRYgZDqADWoXUcCgITesigbGUo9cIAAnmhQA8aLZJZmQkuAB7nkCX69rUy6pSYE-q0KahA4NhIkERwkHvGg0VAHRMEEBx0AAZVRQw8hoGwsSXaw4AAVVFXYYDYBh1FaLYoA8WDQGUNhkBFXxQDwgi0SSZU6MItAEmJBd5gfBInxfQRJXeJd90EQCeKvPi3wjIiQC-H90FkSiRQ8BZOKAA)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the timeUnit in the x2 axis, also setting it to ucthours fixes the time difference.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A status timeline",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "agent": "sarah",
        "start": "2023-01-13T10:36:53.937Z",
        "status": "Transition",
        "end": "2023-01-13T11:38:53.937Z"
      },
      {
        "agent": "sarah",
        "start": "2023-01-13T11:38:53.937Z",
        "status": "Offline",
        "end": "2023-01-13T15:39:53.937Z"
      },
      {
        "agent": "sarah",
        "start": "2023-01-13T15:39:53.937Z",
        "status": "Online",
        "end": "2023-01-13T16:40:26.637Z"
      },
      {
        "agent": "sarah",
        "start": "2023-01-13T16:40:26.637Z",
        "status": "Training",
        "end": "2023-01-13T18:45:26.637Z"
      },
      {
        "agent": "gustavo",
        "start": "2023-01-13T07:36:53.937Z",
        "status": "Transition",
        "end": "2023-01-13T08:38:53.937Z"
      },
      {
        "agent": "gustavo",
        "start": "2023-01-13T08:38:53.937Z",
        "status": "Offline",
        "end": "2023-01-13T10:39:53.937Z"
      },
      {
        "agent": "gustavo",
        "start": "2023-01-13T10:39:53.937Z",
        "status": "Online",
        "end": "2023-01-13T12:40:26.637Z"
      },
      {
        "agent": "gustavo",
        "start": "2023-01-13T12:40:26.637Z",
        "status": "Training",
        "end": "2023-01-13T14:45:26.637Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  "mark": "rect",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "agent"},
    "x": {
      "axis": {"title": "Status Timeline"},
      "field": "start",
      "type": "temporal",
      "timeUnit": "utchours",
      "scale": {
        "domain": [{"hours": 0}, {"hours": 24}],
        "padding": 0
      }
      
    },
    "x2": {"field": "end", "timeUnit": "utchours"},
    "color": {"field": "status", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```